# pointer to pointer assignment not working if used in a separate method

Tags: c++, pointers

Within main, if the line that is commented out is used instead of the one above it, I lose the pointer and nothing gets printed to the console. I must be missing some fundamental property concerning pointers but I thought that when I pass the pointers to x and y into foo(), assignment of them would work the same as it would if the same logic was done locally in main. What am I missing and what would make assignment work correctly within foo()?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

const int maxSize = 3;

struct Item{
    string key;
    string value;
};

struct Node{
    int count;

    Item *item[maxSize + 1];
    Node *branch[maxSize + 1];
};

void foo(Item *x, Item*y)
{
    y = x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Item *x = new Item();
    x->key = "hi";
    x->value = "there";

    Item *y = new Item();

    y = x;
    //foo(x, y);

    Node *p = new Node();
    p->item[1] = y;

    cout << p->item[1]->key << " " << p->item[1]->value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main question is basically something like: "how can I move some code into a function and get the same behaviour?"

Inside `main` you have `y=x`. But before describing how to move that logic into a function, I should say that this line is very strange and probably doesn't do what you want it to do.

But, I'll ignore that and I will pretend that `y=x` in main is 'correct' and that you then want to move that code into a function. The correct way in C++ to move code into functions, without changing behaviour, is to use references.

For example, if you had

```
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b= 0;
    b = a;
}
```

You could do this for the same behaviour:

```
void foo(int &a, int &b) {
    b = a;
}
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b= 0;
    foo(a,b);
}
```

It should be noted that the names of the variables are meaningless. We could write `foo` as follows and it would be identical.

```
void foo(int &left, int &right) {
    right = left;
}
```

Anyway, copy and paste your code into a function and make all parameters into references. In your case, simply

```
void foo(Item *(&x), Item*(&y))
{
    y = x; // does exactly the same as y=x in main, because x and y are references here
}
```

Sometimes, the language can be confusing regarding the placement of `*` and `&`, so the simplest way to turn a parameter `x` into a reference is to put `( )` around it and put the `&` just inside the `( )`. i.e. `x` becomes `(&x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function `foo`, `x` and `y` are local variables (that simply happen to be pointers). If you change their value (the address they point to), like with all local variables, the change is local as well, by definition.

If you want to use the information these pointers offer you (the address of something) to change a value in memory, you can do it like this (in the called function `foo`):

```
*y = *x;
```

Note that this doesn't perform any change to the pointers (since they are local variables), but it changes the value they point to.

If you want to change the pointers of the calling function (not the values they point to), you can still apply the same logic as above, by passing *pointers to the pointers you want to change*:

```
void foo(Item **x, Item **y)
{
    *y = *x;
}
```

Keep in mind that the same assignment has different semantics between caller and callee. See [Aaron McDaid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580448/pointer-to-pointer-assignment-not-working-if-used-in-a-separate-method/29580954#29580954) for a detailed explanation on how to extract similar code into another function while maintaining the correct semantics.

Comment: Is it always true that any method that contains an initialization of a variable using the new keyword should also have that memory freed using delete at the end of the method? Or is that not always true?

Comment: @John Any resource that's taken should also be released. This means that you should make sure your objects are properly deleted.

Comment: @John The simplest case is using `delete` at the end of the method, for every `new` you had. You can also allocate on the stack (without `new`), which means your local objects will get destroyed automatically at return. You can also use smart pointers, which are a form of garbage collection (reference counting) that take care of some special cases for you (like exceptions interrupting the flow of the method). You may have another scheme set up (like a tracing GC library, such as Boehm GC). But in any case, you *do* have to make sure the resources will be properly released one way or another.

Comment: The answer may be misleading. It implies that `*y=*x` in `main` would be equivalent to `*y=*x` inside `foo`. ("you can still apply the same logic as above"). But that's incorrectly. `*y=*x` inside main is actually equivalent to *two* stars inside foo  `**x = **y`  If this seems crazy, then it means we need a more basic answer to reset this conversation

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I don't fully see how my answer implies what you described, but I've tried to clarify it, in any case. If you still think it could be misleading for the OP, please let me know.

Comment: You're right sorry, I didn't realize that your first block of code (`*y=*x`) was preceded by the text "(in the called function foo)". I thought that code was in `main`. I should have read your answer more slowly

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Actually, you were right - I added that after your comment, to make my intention clearer. Glad to know it's okay now.

Answer (score 0):

What `y=x`  does is this make `y` to point to the same object `x` points to, leaving away anythig `y` is actually pointing.

The key point is that the x and y of `foo` are not the same x and y of main: they are other pointer pointing to what you say when calling foo.

`y=x` into `foo` has no effect outside of it (it just change the "direction" the local y is "pointing" to)

```
Item *y = new Item();
y = x;
```

in main, then, is a nonsense: you create a new `Item` in memory making y to point towards it, then change the y direction towards the direction of x, (thous making y and x to point to the same object) making the newly allocated Item unreachable.

If you want the item referred by y to look the same of the one referred by x, you should do `*y = *x` and not `y=x`

Think to pointer as "fingers directed towards something".
If you want two different objects to become equal, you have to assign one object to the other, not "reorient" the fingers towards a same one (in your case the empty one)